# Strip out months from two date columns

Tags: python, python-2.7, date, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that has contracts start and end date and a quantity.  How would I strip out the individual months so they can be aggregated and graphed.

```
ex 
Start Date  End Date       Demanded     Customer
1/1/2017    3/31/2017        100            A
2/1/2017    3/31/2017         50            B
```

strip out the months to the following

```
Month       Demand    Customer
1/1/2017     100      A
2/1/2017     100      A
3/1/2017     100      A
2/1/2017      50      B
3/1/2017      50      B
```

End result is to pivot this and then graph with months on the x-axis and total demand on the y-axis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first convert columns with dates [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html).  Then use [`itertuples`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html) and [`date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.date_range.html) with frequency `MS` (start of month) with [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) for creating new expanding `DataFrame`. Last [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) original columns `Quantity Demanded` and `Customer`:

```
df['Start_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start Date'])
df['End_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End Date'])

df1 = pd.concat([pd.Series(r.Index, 
                           pd.date_range(r.Start_Date, r.End_Date, freq='MS')) 
                           for r in df.itertuples()])
        .reset_index()
df1.columns = ['Month','idx']
print (df1)
       Month  idx
0 2017-01-01    0
1 2017-02-01    0
2 2017-03-01    0
3 2017-02-01    1
4 2017-03-01    1

df2 = df1.set_index('idx').join(df[['Quantity Demanded','Customer']]).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df2)
       Month  Quantity Demanded Customer
0 2017-01-01                100        A
1 2017-02-01                100        A
2 2017-03-01                100        A
3 2017-02-01                 50        B
4 2017-03-01                 50        B
```

Comment: when I try this, the column names do not set.

Comment: What was problem? There was different column names?

Comment: df1.columns = ['Month','idx']


Does not work/apply.  The value of df1 is the same after

Comment: .reset_index() - i get a indent error so I just changed this to d1.reset_index()   - then when I run df1.columns = ['Month','idx'] it seems to have no effect.  Is it because df1 is a Series?  (taking a guess)

Comment: You can use one row like `df1 = pd.concat([pd.Series(r.Index,                         pd.date_range(r.Start_Date, r.End_Date, freq='MS')) 
                           for r in df.itertuples()].reset_index()`

Comment: Quick Question, if the Contract date does not start on the 1st on the month, your code omits it.  How can I chnage it so it does not.

Comment: It is really complicated, but this work `df['Start_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(pd.to_datetime(df['Start Date']).values.astype('datetime64[M]'))` or another solution is replace values between `//` to `/1/` - `df['Start_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start Date'].str.replace('/(.*)/', '/1/'))`

Comment: I ended up doign this, just a fyi

Comment: df['Start_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start Date']).apply(lambda dt: dt.replace(day=1))

Answer (score 1):

Using `melt` then `resample('MS')`

```
df['Start Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start Date'])
df['End Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End Date'])

d1 = pd.melt(
    df, ['Demanded', 'Customer'],
    ['Start Date', 'End Date'],
    value_name='Date'
).drop('variable', 1).set_index('Date')

d1.groupby('Customer').apply(lambda df: df.resample('MS').ffill()) \
    .reset_index(0, drop=True) \
    .reset_index()

        Date  Demanded Customer
0 2017-01-01       100        A
1 2017-02-01       100        A
2 2017-03-01       100        A
3 2017-02-01        50        B
4 2017-03-01        50        B
```